# Memory Organising for big data

Tags: c++, oop, memory, bigdata

I have a class that holds say 4 integers. I need to create 1 millions instances of the above class. How should I create..?

Naive approach is:
*Class arrMyObjectes[1000000];*

But it needs 1million * sizeof(obj) = **16Millions bytes of continous memory block****, which will be hard to get..**

The better approach will be:
*Class *arrMyObjectes[1000000];*

Now we will create a 1000000 objects using ***new*** and we will store the pointers in the above mentioned pointer array...Even in this case we need 1 millions*sizeof(pointer) = *4million bytes continous memory block.. also seems like hard to get..*

Is there any other better approach.

Comment: You may want to try `std::vector< MyClass> container(100000);`.  The vector allocates memory dynamically.

Comment: Do you **need** access to all the items at the same time?

Comment: 16MB of contiguous memory is pretty easy to find on a desktop. Also the fact that the memory is contiguous will have **tremendous** (beneficial) effects on performance if you do any linear processing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the reply.. and Yes I need access to all items at the same time and may I know how does that matter..

Comment: If you don't need to iterate through all of the items at the same time, you could divide up the data into smaller pieces and work on those pieces.  For example, operate on 10,000 integers at a time.  Read them in, process them; read in the next group, process that group.

Answer (score 3):

What about `std::deque<Class> objects(1000000);` or `std::list<Class> objects(1000000);`. Those containers are non contiguous.

In case the implementation tries to grab a contiguous block for those constructors you can generate them individually:

```
std::deque<Class> objects;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    objects.emplace_back();
```

Same for `std::list`.

**Reference:** [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Answer (score 2):

16 MB or 4MB is not that hard to get if you have 2GB ram or more. It may actually be better performance-wise if you iterate over it.

Otherwise, you can use a non-contiguous container like mentioned by Galik, but for small items (and your class is 16 bytes) it's really not optimal because it fragments the memory and assuming you're on a 64 bits machine uses 8 additional bytes per item, for the pointer. 4 additional bytes if you're on a 32 bits machine.

Meaning you'd actually use 24 MB of (fragmented) memory instead of 16.

Short version: if you manipulate small items (like your class), stick to using vectors, it will improve performance and memory usage. 16 MB contiguous memory is not that much anymore nowadays.